# JabRef BibTex data from DOI not working

Tags: windows, latex, bibliography

For a few weeks now, when I try to fetch the BibTex data for a publication using the DOI field, nothing happens. I updated JabRef to 3.8.2 and it didn't help. Does anyone know a solution or at least the cause for this?

Comment: Hello Ian. Try to create a new item and put inside the doi. Did it open the article page if you click in the icon under the doi column in the preview?

Comment: @Hastur Yes, the DOI link works when I clock on the bar code symbol. By the way, the message I get in the status bar when trying to retrieve info based on the DOI is "Cannot get infro based on given DOI: xxx"

Comment: Just a past reference with the same problem [ [1](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/216) ]. That time was not jabref depending... there was suggested a workaround.